# ADF - Loading CSVs with no columns names to AzureDB

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

New to ADF, came across this issue the other day. Is there way to deal with mapping a  CSV file that come in from the blob without any headers and load them into the AzureDB?

Anyone else came across such thing? Any tips/advance greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Ryoss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Mapping feature in Copy activity will map the column ordinals to the SQL schema.

**First** create a Dataset for the CSV file and uncheck "First row as header":

[image]

On the "Schema" tab, it will show the number of columns but no names:

[image]

**Second** create a Dataset for the SQL Table with the schema:

[image]

**Finally** on the Copy activity "Mapping" tab, press "Import schemas" to reveal the ordinal mapping:

[image]

**Aside:** If you need something more robust, you can do this in a Data Flow, where the Source columns will have actual names:

[image]